# Compute fourier series of $f(x)=e^{bx}$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I just applied the straightforward method by calculating $a_0,$ $a_n$ and $b_n$. I got that

$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\pi b}dx=\frac{2\sinh(\pi b)}{\pi b}.\tag{1}$$

By fractions by parts twice and solving for the original integral I get

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\pi b}\cos(nx) dx=\frac{2b(-1)^n\sinh(\pi b)}{n^2+b^2},\tag2$$

and in a similar fashion

$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\pi b}\sin(nx) dx=\frac{2n(-1)^n\sinh(\pi b)}{n^2+b^2}.\tag2$$

Thus

$$e^{bx}=\frac{\sinh(\pi b)}{\pi b}+\frac{2\sinh(\pi b)}{\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+b^2}(b\cos(nx)+n\sin(nx)).$$

**Questions:**

1. Is this correct and how do I check it? I tried plugging in and plotting both sides for $b=3$ but Maple can't plot the RHS, it just loads and nothing happens.
2. Is this the preferred way to go or would things be simpler if we went the complex way by computing $c_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things get simpler if we use complex way. We find that
$$\begin{align*}
a_n+ib_n&=\frac1{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{bx}e^{inx}\mathrm dx \\&=\frac1{\pi(b+in)}\left(e^{(b+in)\pi}-e^{-(b+in)\pi}\right)\\
&=\frac{(b-in)(-1)^n}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}2\sinh(b\pi)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^nb}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}2\sinh(b\pi)-i\frac{(-1)^nn}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}2\sinh(b\pi).
\end{align*}$$ So we have
$$
a_n=\frac{(-1)^nb}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}2\sinh(b\pi),\quad n\ge 1
$$ and
$$
b_n=-\frac{(-1)^nn}{\pi(b^2+n^2)}2\sinh(b\pi) ,\quad n\ge 1.
$$ It looks like you have the wrong sign for $b_n$.

Comment: This seems like a neat way of dong it, however, why is $c_n=a_n+ib_n?$ I know that $a_n=c_n+c_{-n}$ and $b_n=i(c_n-c_{-n})$ so $$c_n=(c_n+c_{-n})+i(i(c_n-c_{-n}))=2c_{-n}.$$

Comment: @Parseval  It seems that your definition of $c_n$ is $$c_n = \frac{1}{\color{red}2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx} \mathrm dx,$$ right? It's a standard way of defining Fourier coefficients, but it is different from what I calculated, which is $2c_{-n}$. Your formula correctly gives this result: $a_n + ib_n =2c_{-n}$. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of my $c_n$ indeed. Well, if you computed $2c_{-n}$ then should it not be $$c_{-n}=c_n/2=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{inx}dx...??$$

Comment: @Parseval Oh, I should have pointed out that $c_n \ne 2c_{-n}$. Since derivation of it is based on the false assumption $c_n = a_n +ib_n$.

Comment: Ah..ofcourse! Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, now that I got $a_n$ and $b_n$, what way would be easiest to get $a_0?$ Is it by the regular formula or by plugging $n=0$ in $a_n?$